# How do I read a parameter from a text file in a FORTRAN module?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a module to define variables as follows:

`MODULE vardef
    Real(8), parameter :: foo = 5.0
END MODULE vardef`

However, I would like to store the value of `foo` in a text file and read from it. I tried the following:

`MODULE vardef
    Real(8) :: fooread
    Open(unit = 5, file = 'ModelInput.txt', status = 'old')
    Read(5,*) fooread
    Real(8), parameter :: foo = fooread
END MODULE vardef`

But I get the following compilation error:

`Error: Unexpected OPEN statement in MODULE at (1)`

Is there any way to define a parameter using a text file?

I am using the GNU FORTRAN compiler Version 6.3.0.

Thanks for the help!